# IE9/10 Toolbar located on same level as Favorites

Tags: internet-explorer-9, toolbar, internet-explorer-10

Is there any way (or hack) to get other toolbars on the same level as the Favorites bar.
The best I can get is the Command toolbar to the same level - the Favorites seems completely unmovable.
I have one toolbar that consists of one icon and it is nonsensical that a whole toolbar has to be used just for this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered totally removing the favorites bar? Right click on the toolbar area and unselect `Favorites Bar`.  You can always get to the favorites by using the star icon on the right hand side.

[image: Favorites Icon]

Comment: The point of having the favorites toolbar is that they're one click away. And I would still have a toolbar consisting of one icon...

Comment: @user2036277 - Just trying to give you some alternatives. One other thing I do is pin my favorite sites to the task bar: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg618532(v=vs.85).aspx#howto Then you can just one-click your site in the task bar.

Comment: I detest the look of using that method and still I have a toolbar with...oh I'm repeating myself...